# How to make shape key "presets"

Tags: mesh, objects, shape-keys

I'm looking for a way to have multiple shape keys be combined to form a single shape key. If anyone's familiar with Daz studio, I'm looking for something similar to a parameter. Is this something that is achievable in Blender?

I'm not looking to make a new shape key, looking for something that saves a little space.

Answer (score 2):

Next to the 'Shape Keys' list there is a dark gray button with an arrow, it will open a menu which has an operator called 'New Shape from Mix'. It'll make a combined shape key.

[image: image of the shape-keys operators menu]